# Payumoney Error while integrating codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, payment, gateway, payumoney

I am working on codeigniter and integrating the payumoney payment gateway. Here I have a registration form and there are various fields in the form Now what I am doing I want to add payumoney payment gateway but the problem is this when I add write the fname or amount from myself the it works fine but while I use $this->input->post('first_name') It shows error like follows
 [click to view the image (Here is the error in the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNouB.png)

Here is the data variables
[the values for data array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yprZy.png)

My code is follows :

```
function checkout() {
        $this->load->config('payu');
        $MERCHANT_KEY = $this->config->item('MERCHANT_KEY');
        $SALT = $this->config->item('SALT');
        $PAYU_BASE_URL = $this->config->item('PAYU_BASE_URL');
        $action = '';
        $txnid = substr(hash('sha256', mt_rand() . microtime()), 0, 20);

        $udf1 = '';
        $udf2 = '';
        $udf3 = '';
        $udf4 = '';
        $udf5 = '';
        $amount = $this->input->post('corporate_plan_rate');
        $productinfo = 'test';
        $fname = $this->input->post('user_name');
        $email = $this->input->post('user_email');


        $data = array(
            'mkey' => $MERCHANT_KEY,
            'tid' => $txnid,
            'MERCHANT_KEY'=>$MERCHANT_KEY,
            'txnid'=>$txnid,
            'SALT'=>$SALT,
//          'hash' => $hash,
            'amount' => $amount,
            'pinfo' => $productinfo,
            'name' => $fname,
            'productinfo'=>$productinfo,
            'mailid' => $email,
            'phoneno' => '9646403748',
            'udf1' => $udf1,
            'udf2' => $udf2,
            'udf3' => $udf3,
            'udf4' => $udf4,
            'udf5' => $udf5,
        );

        $this->load->view('payu/checkout.php', $data);
    }
```

and here is my view page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
        <script>
//          $(function () {
//              setTimeout(function () {
//                  $('form').submit();
//              }, 2000)
//          });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $hashstring = $MERCHANT_KEY . '|' . $txnid . '|' . $amount . '|' . $productinfo . '|' . $name . '|' . $mailid . '|' . $udf1 . '|' . $udf2 . '|' . $udf3 . '|' . $udf4 . '|' . $udf5 . '||||||' . $SALT;

        $hash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $hashstring));
        ?>
        <h2>PayU Form</h2>
        <br/>
        <form method="post" name="payuForm" action="https://test.payu.in/_payment">

            <input name="key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $mkey ?>" />
            <input name="txnid" type="hidden"  value="<?php echo $tid ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?php echo $hash ?>"/>

            <input name="amount" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>" />

            <input name="productinfo" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $pinfo; ?>">

            <input type="hidden" name="service_provider" value="payu_paisa" size="64" />
            <input name="udf1" type="hidden" value="">
            <input name="udf2" type="hidden" value="">
            <input name="udf3" type="hidden" value="">
            <input name="udf4" type="hidden" value="">
            <input name="udf5" type="hidden" value="">

            <input name="firstname" id="firstname" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/>

            <input name="email" id="email"  type="hidden"  value='<?php echo $mailid; ?>'>

            <input name="phone"   type="hidden"  value="<?php echo $phoneno; ?>">
            <input name="surl" type="hidden" value="<?php echo base_url('payu/success'); ?>" size="64" />
            <input name="furl" type="hidden" value="<?php echo base_url('payu/cancel'); ?>" size="64" />
            <input name="curl" type="hidden" value="<?php echo base_url('payu/cancel'); ?>" />

            <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="Click Here for Payment" class="btn btn-info btn-block" >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please help me find out the problem and resolve it out.. Thanx

Comment: I got the same error message from payumoney side when I use original merchant key and salt in test URL. So i strongly recommend you to recheck your merchant key and salt. And if that is not your problem can you post print_r($data) value along with the question. You can remove merchant key and salt and other sessitive information if you want before posting.

Comment: Okay that are used for just test account. So I have posted the $data

Comment: Hi James I have added the print_r($data). please check I am using codeiginter

Comment: Hi James one thing also I want to share with you that When I am using this using core php then It working fine, But using codeignitor there is the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please completely replace your controller function with below codes

```
function checkout() 
{

        $MERCHANT_KEY = "enter your test merchant key here";
        $SALT = "enter your test salt here";

        $txnid = substr(hash('sha256', mt_rand() . microtime()), 0, 20);

        $udf1 = '';
        $udf2 = '';
        $udf3 = '';
        $udf4 = '';
        $udf5 = '';
        $amount = $this->input->post('corporate_plan_rate');
        $productinfo = 'test_payment';
        $fname = $this->input->post('user_name');
        $email = $this->input->post('user_email');

        $hashstring = $MERCHANT_KEY . '|' . $txnid . '|' . $amount . '|' . $productinfo . '|'. $fname . '|' . $email .'|'.$udf1.'|' .$udf2.'|' .$udf3.'|'.$udf4.'|'.$udf5.'||||||'. $SALT;

        $hash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $hashstring));

        $data = array(
            'mkey' => $MERCHANT_KEY,
            'tid' => $txnid,
            'hash' => $hash,
            'amount' => $amount,
            'pinfo' => $productinfo,
            'name' => $fname,
            'productinfo'=>$productinfo,
            'mailid' => $email,
            'phoneno' => '9646403748',
        );

        $this->load->view('payu/checkout', $data);
}
```

Now completely replace your checkout view file with following codes

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2>PayU Form</h2>
        <br/>
        <form method="post" name="payuForm" action="https://test.payu.in/_payment">

            <input name="key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $mkey ?>" />
            <input name="txnid" type="hidden"  value="<?php echo $tid ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?php echo $hash ?>"/>

            <input name="amount" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>" />

            <input name="productinfo" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $pinfo; ?>">

            <input type="hidden" name="service_provider" value="payu_paisa" size="64" />
            <input name="udf1" type="hidden" value="">
            <input name="udf2" type="hidden" value="">
            <input name="udf3" type="hidden" value="">
            <input name="udf4" type="hidden" value="">
            <input name="udf5" type="hidden" value="">

            <input name="firstname" id="firstname" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/>

            <input name="email" id="email"  type="hidden"  value='<?php echo $mailid; ?>'>

            <input name="phone"   type="hidden"  value="<?php echo $phoneno; ?>">

            <input name="surl" type="hidden" value="<?php echo base_url('payu/success'); ?>" size="64" />
            <input name="furl" type="hidden" value="<?php echo base_url('payu/cancel'); ?>" size="64" />
            <input name="curl" type="hidden" value="<?php echo base_url('payu/cancel'); ?>" />

            <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="Click Here for Payment" class="btn btn-info btn-block" >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please try above code without adding any of your own codes for testing and if the same error occurs comment below.

Comment: Yes same problem occured. Some my code runs but maximum times it not able to run. I can not understand what is the problem.

Comment: Actually what I am doing, I have a registration form and user fills the form and then form submitted to checkout method and first all the form fields are inserted into database then all the post fields are done like the above. Then redirected to payment gateway and so on.. Some times I manually enter the amount value in the controller at the place of $this->input->post('corporate_plan_rate'), It worked for me 1 time before. but the same code is not working now. So please resolve the problem. Code working good in core php code. Thanx

Comment: @BirendraSingh so if you manually enter values in $amount, $fname and $email the above code work fine right? I test the above codes in a test CodeIgniter project using my test salt and key and it works fine for me. Please call payumoney support person to ensure that your test salt and key is working and correct.

Comment: And you are using the same process what I am using un codeigniter??

Comment: If you give your email I will send the test codeignitor project with only above codes that work fine for me.

Comment: Yes pls send me at birendra.3092@gmail.com... Thnx

Comment: I send you the mail. Fill it with your key and salt and if same problem occurred then contact payumoney as there is some problem with your salt and key

Comment: Thank u so much james for your support... Hope i will be able to resolve the issue. Thnx

Comment: James.. Actually we cannot use test account now here.. So we need to check everything in live. I was so frustrated why is it not working... So sad.. Hahaha

Comment: @BirendraSingh did you resolve your problems in test account. If soo then just changing the merchant id and salt of test account to production will work fine in live. Remember you need to change your form action url to  https://secure.payu.in/_payment . So what is exactly your problem?